# Button interaction question about discord. Py

Tags: discord.py, discord-buttons

How do i use bot.wait_for for button_clicked and how do i get interaction id?

And if view is running in two guilds at same time will it be different or same? Because i want to run some function on it so it might get called for another guild

Comment: You have two questions in one. Please ask them seperately

Answer (score 1):

`button_clicked` event for `bot.wait_for` was only for `discord-components`, which is outdated and should not be used.

The best solution is to use the `button.callback` function.

```
class MyView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
    @discord.ui.button(label=“Click me!”)
    async def mybutton_callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        await interaction.response.send_message(content=“Hello world”)
```

The `wait_for` function waits for an event to happen, in this case, `button_clicked` does not exist within Discord.py and was in `discord-components`.

This code gives a basic representation of how a button works in Discord.py.

For more information, [discord.ui.View](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#view), [discord.ui.Button](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#button).